# How To Receive Output From A Child Process' STDOUT Without Blocking or Poling

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, parent-child

I have a long-running console-based application `Sender` that sends simple text to STDOUT using non-buffered output such as `cout << "Message" << flush()`.  I want to create an MFC dialog-based application (named `Receiver`) that starts `Sender` and can read it's output.  `Receiver` should also be able to detect when `Sender` has died, or be able to kill `Sender` if it wants to.  `Sender` knows nothing of `Reciever`, and I can't change `Sender`'s code.

My first attempt was to create pipes with redirected STDIN and STDOUT for the child process and use asynchronous ReadFileEx calls to read in `Sender`'s data.  This isn't working correctly, and [I've posted a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661106/overlapped-readfileex-on-child-process-redirected-stdout-never-fires) about those specific problems.

My question is, how should I be doing this, in general architectural terms?  I don't want `Receiver`'s main loop to block or poll, but should use some flavor of [Wait function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 basic options.  Option 1 you've already tried, doing asynchronous (aka nonblocking) IO to read/write from the child process.  Option 2 is to create a separate thread in the Receiver process that does blocking reads/writes from/to the child process.

I'd recommend option 2, I find it much easier.  You then, of course, have the problem of how to get the data from the helper thread to the main thread.  You'll need to use locks and maybe semaphores for that.  It should be less of a hassle than nonblocking IO, however.

Comment: I've found pretty much the same wrt asynchronous I/O. I usually get the data from the worker thread to the main thread by sending a message though -- avoids most of the hassle of locks, semaphores, etc.

Comment: +1 from me. I've successfully implemented option 2 when I was doing this and it's much less of a hassle than to mess with nonblocking IO.