# Overlapped ReadFileEx on Child Process' Redirected STDOUT Never Fires

Tags: c++, windows, redirect

I have a long-running console-based application Sender that sends simple text to STDOUT using non-buffered output such as cout << "Message" << flush(). I want to create an MFC dialog-based application (named Receiver) that starts Sender and can read it's output. Receiver should also be able to detect when Sender has died, or be able to kill Sender if it wants to. Sender knows nothing of Reciever, and I can't change Sender's code.

I have asked a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661041/how-to-receive-output-from-a-child-process-stdout-without-blocking-or-looping) about the best way to do this.  My first attempt was to create pipes with redirected STDIN and STDOUT for the child process and use asynchronous ReadFileEx calls to read in Sender's data. This isn't working correctly, because the ReadFileEx function only fires once, and only with zero bytes transferred even though I know for a fact that `Sender` is sending data.

I am creating 2 pipes with redirected STDIN and STDOUT, ala [this MS example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx):

```
// allow the child process to inherit handles
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {0};
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.bInheritHandle = 1;

// create pipes with rerouted stdin & stdout
CreatePipe(&handles[h_Child_StdOut_Read], &handles[h_Child_StdOut_Write], &sa, 0);
SetHandleInformation(handles[h_Child_StdOut_Read], HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
CreatePipe(&handles[h_Child_StdIn_Read], &handles[h_Child_StdIn_Write], &sa, 0);
SetHandleInformation(handles[h_Child_StdIn_Read], HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
```

...`Receiver` then goes on to start `Sender` via CreateProcess():

```
// create child process
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
STARTUPINFO si = {0};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.hStdOutput = handles[h_Child_StdOut_Write];
si.hStdInput = handles[h_Child_StdIn_Read];
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcess( 0, "Sender.EXE", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
handles[h_Child_Process] = pi.hProcess;
handles[h_Child_Thread] = pi.hThread;
```

My main loop is based on WaitForObjectsEx, placed in to an alertable wait state to support the asynch file read.  I am waiting on two handles: one that signals when `Sender` dies prematurely, and one that signals when `Receiver`'s main thread wants `Sender` to die.  Before starting the loop, I kick off an overlapped (asynchronous) file read operation on `Sender`'s STDOUT.  Ignore the obvious memory leaks and other hacks -- this is illustrative:

```
vector<HANDLE> wait_handles;
wait_handles.push_back(handles[h_Die_Sig]);
wait_handles.push_back(handles[h_Child_Process]);

for( bool cont = true; cont; )
{
    IO* io = new IO;
    memset(io, 0, sizeof(IO));
    io->buf_size_ = 16 * 1024;
    io->buf_ = new char[io->buf_size_];
    memset(io->buf_, 0, io->buf_size_);
    io->thread_ = &param;
    io->file_ = handles[h_Child_StdOut_Read];
    if( !ReadFileEx(io->file_, io->buf_, io->buf_size_, io, OnFileRead) )
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        string err_msg = util::strprintwinerr(err);
    }

    DWORD rc = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(wait_handles.size(), &wait_handles[0], FALSE, INFINITE, TRUE);

    // ...
}
```

The `IO` object above is derived publicly from `OVERLAPPED`:

```
struct IO : public OVERLAPPED
{
    char* buf_;
    DWORD buf_size_;
    DWORD read_;
    ThreadParam* thread_;
    HANDLE file_;
};
```

When the overlapped Read function completes, I read the incoming data and generate a string:

```
void CALLBACK OnFileRead(DWORD err, DWORD bytes, OVERLAPPED* ovr)
{
    IO* io = static_cast<IO*>(ovr);
    string msg(io->buf_, bytes);
}
```

`Sender` knows nothing of `Receiver`, and it sends text to the console using very simple, but non-buffered means.

The problem:  I know that `Sender` is sending data to its STDOUT, but my `OnFileRead` function is called only once, and only with zero bytes transferred.

Why can't I receive `Sender`'s output this way?  Do I have a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How does this compile?  The 4th argument to ReadFileEx() is an OVERLAPPED*, not IO*, whatever that is.

Comment: @Hans:  `IO` is derived from `OVERLAPPED.  I've added the declaration above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo:

```
CreatePipe(&handles[h_Child_StdOut_Read], &handles[h_Child_StdOut_Write], &sa, 0);
SetHandleInformation(handles[h_Child_StdOut_Read], HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
CreatePipe(&handles[h_Child_StdIn_Read], &handles[h_Child_StdIn_Write], &sa, 0);
SetHandleInformation(handles[h_Child_StdIn_Read], HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
```

change the last one to

```
SetHandleInformation(handles[h_Child_StdIn_Write], HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
```

that's also what they do at the MSDN example.

Answer (score 11):

Besides the error pointed out by @DyP, you are assuming that `CreatePipe` opened the handle in overlapped mode.  **Your assumption is incorrect**.  Microsoft [documents it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365141.aspx):

> Asynchronous (overlapped) read and write operations are not supported
>   by anonymous pipes. This means that you cannot use the ReadFileEx and
>   WriteFileEx functions with anonymous pipes. In addition, the
>   lpOverlapped parameter of ReadFile and WriteFile is ignored when these
>   functions are used with anonymous pipes.

(Indeed, if you look inside `kernel32.dll`, on Windows XP for example, `CreatePipe` does not set the lower bit on the seventh parameter to `NtCreateNamedPipeFile`; that bit *is* set when `CreateNamedPipe` is called with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`.)

**Look for Dave Hart's [`MyCreatePipeEx`](http://www.davehart.net/remote/PipeEx.c)** implementation; it can be used as a drop-in replacement for `CreatePipe` when overlapped I/O is needed.  Simply change `PipeSerialNumber++` to `InterlockedIncrement(&PipeSerialNumber)` to avoid race conditions in MT code.

Comment: I actually figured this out long ago, but your answer will be helpful to future visitors.