# Redirecting stdout from another program in C++

Tags: c++, stdout

I'm writing a unit test and therefore, cannot change the code within the file that I'm testing. The code that I'm testing has messages in cout that I am trying to redirect into a file to check to make sure that the program is outputting the right messages. Does anyone have a way to redirect stdout in another program that won't cause a lag? I have tried freopen() and that causes my program to hang for some reason.

Comment: It might be a bit OS specific..

Comment: This question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257509/freopen-equivalent-for-c-streams).

Comment: Consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661106/overlapped-readfileex-on-child-process-redirected-stdout-never-fires).  Definitly not a dupe, but related.  Might help.

Comment: After redirecting, did you call `flush()` after the code under test had run its full course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `filebuf` then replace `cout`'s streambuf with it:

```
{
  std::filebuf f;
  f.open("output.txt", std::ios::out);
  std::streambuf* o = std::cout.rdbuf(&f);
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;  // endl will flush the stream
  std::cout.rdbuf(o);
}
```

You need to restore `cout`'s original streambuf again (or set it to a null pointer) or it will probably crash when the global streams are flushed and destroyed, because the `filebuf` will already have gone out of scope.

Comment: Is `.rdbuf(0)` intended to be `.rdbuf(o)`?

Comment: This has caused it to start to hang again somehow. Is there something you know of that cause it not to hang?

Comment: It works for me in a small test. Have you run it in a debugger to see where it hangs?

Comment: I think the reason it may be hanging is that it is running within another set of macros that I cannot change that also use stdout. Is that possible?

Comment: Apparently my standard-fu is failing me here -- where does the standard say that `cout.rdbuf(0)` is equivalent to what you have?

Comment: @ildjarn, I didn't say it's equivalent, I said it "works" i.e. it won't crash.  Leaving `cout` referring to the `filebuf` after it goes out of scope is unsafe, restoring the original streambuf _or_ clearing  `cout`'s streambuf avoids that problem.

Comment: Yes, but "works" is a meaningless word without context/guarantees... I understand the rationale for needing to unset the `filebuf`, but I'm unclear as to why `cout.rdbuf(0);` should work.

Comment: @Annika, anything else directly using `stdout` _should_ be unaffected, replacing the streambuf affects operations done through the `cout` object, not the `stdout` file descriptor.

Comment: @ildjarn, you want [ios::Init] i.e. 27.5.3.1.6
  in C++11, which says that after the last `Init` is destroyed `cout.flush()` is called, which is UB if `cout.rdbuf()` is a dangling pointer, but according to [ostream.unformatted] 27.7.3.7
 paragraph 7 is a no-op if `rdbuf()` is null. Happy? You owe me two standard references now ;)

Comment: I've paid my standard-reference dues on this site already, but I'll keep that in mind. ;-] Thanks for the answer. :-]

Comment: Turns out that .rdbuf(0) was part of the problem and only .rdbuf(o) worked for me. I also had another error that was causing the hanging. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'open()' and 'dup2()'. You can use the helpers provided below. An example of how to use them:

```
void
code_to_test ()
{
    std::cout << "Here we go" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Danger danger" << std::endl;
}

run_test(code_to_test);
```

The `run_test` helper invokes redirection, and runs the test code.

```
template <typename TEST> void
run_test (TEST t, bool append = false) {
    flush_output();
    Redirect o(1, "/tmp/test_stdout", append);
    Redirect e(2, "/tmp/test_stderr", append);
    t();
    flush_output();
}
```

The `flush_output` helper flushes the streams.

```
void flush_output () {
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
    std::cout.flush();
    std::cerr.flush();
}
```

The `Redirect` class effects the redirection in the constructor. It restores the original descriptors back in the destructor.

```
class Redirect
{
    int m_what;
    int m_old_what;
public:
    Redirect (int what, std::string where, bool append = false)
        : m_what(what), m_old_what(dup(what)) {
        int flags = O_CREAT|O_WRONLY;
        if (append) flags |= O_APPEND;
        int f = open(where.c_str(), flags, 0660);
        dup2(f, m_what);
        close(f);
    }
    ~Redirect () {
        dup2(m_old_what, m_what);
        close(m_old_what);
    }
};
```